# Passing same arguments to multiple functions - Python

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

In the GPA calculating program below, my two functions take the same parameters. What is the best way to pass the same parameters to two or more functions? Thank you!

```
def main():
    cumulative(ee311=3, cpre281=3, math207=3.67, ee332=3, jlmc101=4)
    print "Your semester 5 gpa is:", sem_5(ee311=3, cpre281=3, math207=3.67, ee332=3, jlmc101=4)[0]

def cumulative(ee311, cpre281, math207, ee332, jlmc101):
    qpts_so_far = 52 + 40.97 + 47.71 + 49
    total_qpts = qpts_so_far + sem_5(ee311=3, cpre281=3, math207=3.67, ee332=3, jlmc101=4)[1]
    total_gpa = total_qpts/(13 + 13 + 13 + 15 + 17)
    print "Your cumulative GPA is:", total_gpa

def sem_5(ee311=3, cpre281=3, math207=3.67, ee332=3, jlmc101=4):
    sem_5_qpts = 4*ee311 + 4*cpre281 + 3*math207 + 3*ee332 + 3*jlmc101
    sem_5_gpa = (sem_5_qpts)/17.0
    return sem_5_gpa, sem_5_qpts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: FYI: Your `cumulative` function never uses the arguments passed to it. Did you mean to pass them on to `sem_5`? If so, you'd have an easier time changing it to `def cumulative(**kwargs)`, and then call `+ sem_5(**kwargs)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could pass the same dictionary to each using `**` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)):

```
args = dict(ee311=3, cpre281=3, math207=3.67, ee332=3, jlmc101=4)
cumulative(**args)
print "Your semester 5 gpa is:", sem_5(**args)[0]
```

Comment: A single start with a tuple/list for the args would work fine here too.